# How can I connect two created ellipses?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I have a code that will paint an ellipse whenever the mouse is clicked.I want to connect the previous ellipse with the new painted ellipse with a line like in the picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEGEH.jpg)

My code is

```
import sys
from turtle import pos
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRectF, QPointF
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QTransform, QBrush, QColor, QPen, QPainterPath
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsPixmapItem, QSizePolicy, QSpacerItem, QGraphicsObject
 
 
class MouseBrushObject(QGraphicsObject):
    def __init__(self):
        QGraphicsObject.__init__(self)
        self._size = 10
        self._x = 0
        self._y = 0
        self._pen = QPen(Qt.red, 5)
        self._brush = QBrush(Qt.red, 5)
        self._px = 0
        self._py = 0
 
    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        #rect = self.boundingRect()
        painter.setPen(self._pen)
        painter.setBrush(self._brush)
        painter.drawEllipse(QPointF(self._x,self._y), 10,10)
        self._px = self._x
        self._py = self._y
        print(QPointF(self._x,self._y))
        print(self._x)
        print(self._px)
        
        #painter.drawLine(self._x,self._y, 5, 5)
 
    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF(self._x, self._y, self._size, self._size)
 
    def setSize(self, size):
        self._size = size
        
    def setPosition(self, pos):
        self._x = pos.x() - pos.x()/2
        self._y = pos.y() - pos.y()/2
        self.setPos(QPointF(self._x, self._y))

class View(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QGraphicsView.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self._scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.setScene(self._scene)
        pixmap = QPixmap(300, 300)
        self._scene.addItem(QGraphicsPixmapItem(pixmap))
        self._scene.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(Qt.lightGray))
        self.objects = []
 
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        pos = event.pos()
        obj = MouseBrushObject()
        obj.setPosition(pos)
        self.objects.append(obj)
        self._scene.addItem(obj)
 
 
class Viewer(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent=parent)
 
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.view = View(self)
        self.setLayout(layout)
 
        layout.addWidget(self.view)
 
 
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
 
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.viewer = Viewer(self)
 
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.viewer)
        centralwidget = QWidget(self)
        centralwidget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I am thinking of adding drawLine in the paint function, but I can't retrieve the previous x and y because I don't know how to save them. Also, I am thinking of using the qpainterpath, but I don't know how to code it.

Comment: If you don't know how save variables, who wrote `def paint(self, painter, option, widget)` ? Whoever gave you that homework, wanted you to find `painter.drawEllipse(QPointF(self._x,self._y), 10,10)` and was hoping you realize what the next two lines do

Comment: @gnight the paint function has absolutely nothing to do with the problem, as its called by Qt and its a custom implementation.

Comment: @Elle you already have the list of current objects, just get the previous one (if it exists) and get its coordinates. Note that it's unclear why you made such a complex implementation of that MouseBrushObject: why didn't you just use a QGraphicsEllipseItem? Also, items already have coordinates, what's the point of adding your own x and y?

Comment: Most of the code was copy-pasted from [here](https://python-forum.io/thread-22052.html), so that might explain why the OP appears to have very little understanding of it.

Comment: @Elle the fact is that the code you're using is unnecessarily complex. To create a "centered" ellipse, just use `obj = scene.addEllipse(-size/2, -size/2, size, size)`, then `obj.setPos(x, y)`. Then, you should not implement the drawing line *inside* each item, but create a new item (QGraphicsLineItem or QGraphicsPathItem) that uses the `pos()` of the items you want to "connect". The graphics view framework is not immediate, trying to learn it only by copying code found somewhere is terribly difficult, you *must* study the documentation to understand how it works.

Comment: @musicamante, sorry. I ams till new and still learning from pyqt5 I copied the code as reference because I can't find examples in the documentations which hard for me to relate.

Comment: @Elle I can understand that difficulty, but the problem is that it seems that you are actually confused on how the graphics view system works (and how objects interact). For instance, if you want to draw a line between two MouseBrushObject, you cannot draw it inside the `paint()` function, because each item would have its own coordinates and will have no knowledge of the other one (while it seems that you tried to do something like that with that `self._px = self._x`, which is actually pointless). Did you read the whole [Graphics View introduction](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html)?

Comment: @musicamante oh okay but I can't get the correct value of x and y for the `obj.setPos(x,y)`.

Answer (score 0):

(Update)I have already found a way to drawLine using the previous and present ellipse. The points are correct since I have printed it:

[image]

but the problem is will not perfectly fit the two ellipses like in this picture:

[image: result].

I know that the points from the previous and present points are correct, but the line is not corretly drawn.

```
import sys
from turtle import pos
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRectF, QPointF
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QTransform, QBrush, QColor, QPen, QPainterPath
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsPixmapItem, QSizePolicy, QSpacerItem, QGraphicsObject
 
 
class MouseBrushObject(QGraphicsObject):
    def __init__(self):
        QGraphicsObject.__init__(self)
        self._size = 10
        self._x = 0
        self._y = 0
        self._pen = QPen(Qt.red, 5)
        self._brush = QBrush(Qt.red, 5)

 
    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        #rect = self.boundingRect()
        painter.setPen(self._pen)
        painter.setBrush(self._brush)
        painter.drawEllipse(QPointF(self._x,self._y), 10,10)
        #print("hello")
        #print(QPointF(self._x,self._y))
        #print(self._x)
        #print(self._px)
        if not self.prevpos:
            print("current xy: "+"("+str(self._x)+","+str(self._y)+")")
        else:
            print("previous xy: "+"("+str(self._px)+","+str(self._py)+")")
            print("new current xy: "+"("+str(self._x)+","+str(self._y)+")")
            
            painter.drawLines(QPointF(self._px,self._py),QPointF(self._x,self._y))
            #painter.drawLine(self._px,self._py,self._x,self._y)
 
    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF(self._x, self._y, self._size, self._size)
 
    def setSize(self, size):
        self._size = size
        
    def setPosition(self, pos,prevpos):
        self.prevpos = prevpos
        #print("meow")
        #print(prevpos)
        if not prevpos:
            self._x = pos.x() - pos.x()/2
            self._y = pos.y() - pos.y()/2
            #self.setPos(QPointF(self._x, self._y))
        else:
            self._x = pos.x() - pos.x()/2
            self._y = pos.y() - pos.y()/2
            self._px = prevpos.x() - prevpos.x()/2
            self._py = prevpos.y() - prevpos.y()/2
            self.setPos(QPointF(self._x, self._y))

 
 
class View(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QGraphicsView.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self._scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.setScene(self._scene)
        pixmap = QPixmap(300, 300)
        self._scene.addItem(QGraphicsPixmapItem(pixmap))
        #self.setTransform(QTransform().scale(1, 1).rotate(0))
        self._scene.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(Qt.lightGray))
        #self._brushItem = MouseBrushObject()
        self.objects = []
        self.posprev = ""
 
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        
        pos = event.pos()
        
        if not self.posprev:
            obj = MouseBrushObject()
            obj.setPosition(pos,self.posprev)
            self.objects.append(obj)
            self._scene.addItem(obj)
            self.posprev = pos
            #print(pos)
        
        else:
            #print(self.posprev)
            #print(pos)
            obj = MouseBrushObject()
            obj.setPosition(pos,self.posprev)
            self.objects.append(obj)
            self._scene.addItem(obj)
            self.posprev =pos
            
class Viewer(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent=parent)
 
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.view = View(self)
        self.setLayout(layout)
 
        layout.addWidget(self.view)
 
 
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
 
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.viewer = Viewer(self)
 
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.viewer)
        centralwidget = QWidget(self)
        centralwidget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: It's not valid because you're still trying to "fix" a code that was already indicated as wrong under many aspects, and you're still not understanding the coordinate system (did you *actually* read the *whole* Graphics View framework page? Have you understood how relative coordinates work? Did you read the QGraphicsItem documentation?). It's also invalid (again, as already said) because you should *not* draw objects outside the bounding rect of an item: add some points, and resize the view until scroll bars are visible, scroll around and you'll see that some items will disappear "randomly".